# How Disqus facebook login dont have the - 'dont give the site my email' option

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

when i try to use facebook login in my website and i asked for email adress when the user login facebook ask them something like: do you want to give them your email? yes no.

but when i check Disqus login with facebook, facebook dont give me the option to login but dont give them the email its just say:
DISQUS will receive the following info: your public profile, friend list and email address.

how do i do the same in my website? because right now what i have is that when someone log in with facebook and refuse to give me his mail i just ask them for their mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after few days i found it.. by using facebook js sdk and asking for email the user dont have option to refuse